# Apply server side CSS to client

Tags: css, caching, client-side

So I'm trying to figure out how to store a CSS in a client side cache and set the alternating stylesheet from the data in the cache.

I'm developing a site that allows a user to customize the site.  And I think the best route might be to save their changes in a css.  But before it's saved I would like to allow them to preview it throughout the site.

Is it possible to set an alternating Stylesheet to an object and not a file?

Are their any concerns?

Has anyone saved CSS data in a DB then applied it a site?

Thanks 
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Appication["Styles"] = css 

<style>
<% =Application["Styles"}.ToString() %>

</style>
```